# Looking an example to implement autoSelectActiveOption property in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

Case : If user input text in search field for autocomplete and forget to select the option available from list, it skips picking the value. If input text is a valid item in list then it should auto select the option.

I can achieve using some manipulation with input change but there seems an property available already for same. I am trying to explore that.

Please advise how to implement it.

Property listed below in documentation:
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#directives

Simple autocomplete :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbeqrh-t96jvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html